# Why do ReSharper default templates have an "&" in the description?

Tags: templates, resharper

The built in file templates have an "&" in the description. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Is that not a shortcut-key? (If so it would be Alt+C and have an underline when displayed.)

Comment: For me, Alt+C opens up the browser drop down in Visual Studio.

Comment: A short-cut in the listing of the templates, not global or in the main application menu.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a non-global shortcut. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand marks the character to use as a shortcut key when the Generate File menu is displayed. It's not necessary - if one doesn't exist, ReSharper will choose a character as best it can (usually the first char, but it also tries to avoid duplicates). These standard file templates have ampersands to give them well known shortcuts, even if the menu is customised and extra items are added that might conflict.